# The code for my program works once and doesn't loop- gets an error on codeblocks and crashes

Tags: c

The code is as follows:
guessing game , 10 guesses max, prompts user for replay. It crashes after one run. It works fine without the replay() module but then I can't incorporate the replay option. I have tried several different things to no avail. Please kindly help me resolve this in a timely manner. Help is appreciated in advance.
thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void guessGame ();
int replay();
int main()
{

    int selection;


    printf("Welcome to the Number Guess Game! I choose a number between 1 and 100 and you\nhave only 10 chances to guess it!");

    do
    {

        printf("\n\nok, I made my mind!");
        guessGame();
        replay();
    }
    while (replay() != 0);

    printf("Thank you! have a nice day.\n");





    return 0;

}
void guessGame()
{
    int attempt,guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand () % 100 + 1;


    for (guess = 1; (guess < 11 && attempt != r); guess = guess + 1)
    {
        printf("\nWhat is your guess> ");
        scanf("%d",&attempt);
        if (attempt < 1 || attempt > 100)
        {
            printf("Invalid guess!\n");
            guess = guess - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (attempt > r && guess < 10)
                printf("My number is smaller than %d\n",attempt);
            else if (attempt < r && guess < 10)
                printf("My number is larger than %d\n",attempt);
        }

        if ((guess < 9) && (attempt >= 1 && attempt <= 100))
            printf("%d guesses left.\n",(10 - guess));
        if ((guess == 9) &&(attempt >= 1 && attempt <= 100))
            printf("%d guess left.\n",(10 - guess));
    }
    if (attempt == r)
    {
        printf("You did it! My number is %d.\nYou did it in %d guesses.\n",r,guess);
    }
    if (guess >= 10 && attempt != r)
    {
        printf("SORRY! you couldn't guess it with 10 guesses.\nMy number was %d. Maybe next time!\n",r);
    }



}

int replay()
{
    char selection;

    printf("\nDo you want to play again");
    scanf("%c",selection);
    if (selection == 'N')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `replay()` twice -- once in the loop body and ignoring what it returns, and again in the `while()` clause. Why do you need it in the body?

Comment: this line: srand(time(NULL)); which initializes the rand() function is called every time the guessgame() function ins invoked.  the initialization should only be performed once, probably early in the main() function.

Comment: this line: if (selection == 'N')  What about 'n'.  The prompt needs to give the user the range of choices,  I.E. 'N' or 'Y' as part of the prompt, otherwise the use could enter 'n' until forever and the game would not exit.  what if the user typed 'yes', then the game would continue AND when it was time to enter a number, the scanf() would always fail.  1) one need to clear the stdin stream before outputing the prompt for a number OR 2) need to change the format string to " %d" (notice the leading space) so that white space (like a newline or left over characters would be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `scanf()` incorrectly. You need to give the address of the variables to store into:

```
scanf("%c", &selection);
```

Comment: Right, which any decent compiler should refuse to compile if given the proper options.  E.g. `gcc -Wall -Werror`.